# PageContextInfo: Page Context is undefined in sharepoint framework (Webpart)

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, angularjs, sharepoint-framework

I am trying to upgrade an old sharepoint project to the latest sharepoint framework. The client part is built with angular. As in spfx _spPageContextInfo is not available so I tired changing the code to

> this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;

format but it does not work.

I have something like this in code

```
        $scope["proxyScriptTag"] = ["<script type='text/javascript' src='",
        $window["_spPageContextInfo"]["webAbsoluteUrl"],
        "/Scripts/test.js",
        "'></script>"] 
and
var appUrl = $window._spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
```

I tried changing it to

```
        $scope["proxyScriptTag"] = ["<script type='text/javascript' src='",
        this["context"]["pageContext"]["web"]["absoluteUrl"],
        "/Scripts/test.js",
        "'></script>"]
and
var appUrl = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;
```

But I get the following error

> Error: this.context is undefined

This is my first time working with SharePoint so I dont completely understand what is the issue. I think the context is not passed from the main ts file but I am not sure about it.

I am stuck on this problem so Any hint or idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your render method add something like

```
window['webPartContext']=this.context;
```

In the js file you can access the pageContext using something like

```
window.webPartContext.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl
```

Answer (score 1):

spfx uses typescript. in typescript `this` context doesnt behave like in javascript. The reason it doesnt is javascript is **not** strongly typed where typescript **is** strongly typed (typesafe).

you could utilize the flat arrow method:

```
$(document).ready((n, m) => yourmethod.run(n, m));
```

explained here:

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

you can find possible solutions and workarounds here to get the javascript version of `this`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627138/typescript-this-scoping-issue-when-called-in-jquery-callback